# How to instantiate AngularFireAuth and AngularFirestore for integration testing?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'd like to write some Karma/Jasmine tests to make sure my angular backend services are acting as expected, but I'm having trouble getting an instance AngularFireAuth and which I need to pass to the constructor of my various services.

For example the constructor of my AuthService looks like this, and I guess Angular knows how to provide these params somehow for dependency injection, since my app is running as expected.  But for testing, I would really like to have more fined grained ability to call specific methods on my services and confirm that my observables are responding as expected.

```
constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,

  ) { ... }
```

But I would like to instantiate them by manually, so I can just instantiate my services as instances manually in my test code, without having to rely on a testbed and mocks and spies which is what I keep seeing in the various google results on this subject.  I would like to test against my real Firestore backend, not a mock, sort of like in RubyOnRails where you test against a dev database on the server.

However, I can't figure out how to manually create an instance of AngularFireAuth and AngularFirestore for these tests, so I can provide these to the constructor of my services. Is this possible or am I just barking up wrong tree?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try provide angularfire module in the TestBed config as follow

```js
    // data.service.spec.ts
    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

    import { DataService } from './data.service';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

    describe('DataService', () => {
      let service: DataService;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
            AngularFirestoreModule
          ],
          declarations: [ ],
          providers: [ ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(DataService);
      });

      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });


      it('query should return data', (done) => {
        service.getQuery().subscribe((data) => {
          console.log('test data');
          console.log(data);

          expect(data).toEqual({text: 'test'});
          done();
        });
      });
    });

    // data.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class DataService {

      public constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

      getQuery() {
        return this.firestore
          .collection<LogData>('logs', ref => ref.where('text', '==', 'test'))
          .get()
          .pipe(
            filter(ref => !ref.empty),
            map(ref => ref.docs[0].data() as LogData)
          );
      }
    }

    interface LogData {
      text: string;
    }
```

updated

example for AngularFireAuth

```js
    // login.service.spec.ts

    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { LoginService } from './login.service';
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

    describe('LoginService', () => {
      let service: LoginService;

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
            AngularFireAuthModule
          ],
          declarations: [ ],
          providers: [ ]
        });
        service = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
      });

      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('signin should return user object', async () => {
        const loginData = {
          email: 'test@user.com',
          password: 'test user password'
        };
        const actual = await service.signin(loginData);
        expect(actual.uid).toEqual('S8HuZr2lbTOwUs1bWPNCuEDfpXe2');
      });
    });

    // login.service.ts
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

    export interface LoginData {
      email: string;
      password: string;
    }

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LoginService {

      constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

      async signin(loginData: LoginData) {
        const {email, password} = loginData;

        const responseOk = await this.auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        return responseOk.user;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your query test _doesn't_ actually test anything, in fact it only logs the query to the console.

Comment: @Edric so why i see data from database in my console?

Comment: Because you've _logged the data to the console via `console.log`_? (What I meant by my original comment was that you weren't testing anything at all with Jasmine/Karma methods such as `expect(value).toEqual(value)`)

Comment: the question was howto config not howto assert something

Comment: I'm not so much looking at how to right tests here as I am to get the testbed configured.  This looks like a good start, but I need to find a way to load AngularFireAuth as well as AngularFireStore.

Comment: @user1023110 i add example for AngularFireAuth. is this way have some issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

Both a technical and a philosophical question in one... Nice

### Is it possible?

Yes. You can use the `new` keyword just like with any other class:

```js
const auth      = new AngularFireAuth(...);
const firestore = new AngularFirestore(...);
```

You'd have to instantiate dependencies like `NgZone`, `PLATFORM_ID`, etc. yourself.

AngularFire is open-source. Take a look at the classes to understand what you need to pass their constructors:

[AngularFireAuth](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts)  | [AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/firestore/firestore.ts)

### Am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Feels like it. Three reasons:

1. If you insist on manual instantiation, you probably have your reasons. That being said, manually instantiating dependencies is always a pain in the butt. That's what injectors are for. Consider using the `TestBed` to initialize Firebase just like you did in your app, then using `TestBed.inject(...)` to get the instances you need. You could even create a setup function that will extract them for you each time:

   ```js
   // ==== Your setup file ====
   function setup()
   {
       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           imports: [
               AngularFireModule.initializeApp(YOUR_FIREBASE_CONFIG),
               AngularFirestoreModule,
               // YOUR MODULE HERE
           ]
       });

       const fireAuth  = TestBed.inject(AngularFireAuth);
       const firestore = TestBed.inject(AngularFirestore);
       const auth      = TestBed.inject(AuthService);

       return { fireAuth, firestore, auth };
   }

   // ==== Your test file(s) ====
   let fireAuth;
   let firestore;
   let auth;

   beforeEach(() =>
   {
       ({ fireAuth, firestore, auth } = setup());
   });
   ```
2. You mentioned you don't want mocks, and that you would like *to make sure your angular backend services are acting as expected*. What is it exactly that you're testing?
   Unit testing is an attempt to isolate functionality. Make sure you're testing how **YOUR CODE** works, and not trapping yourself in the "testing someone else's work" paradigm (i.e. testing that Firebase is doing its job ).
3. *confirm that my observables are responding as expected*
   That's great. Now consider the following: Firebase's servers are failing , just at the moment you're running your testing pipeline. Should your test fail? Of course not. That's what spies and mocks are for: isolation & independency.

### Other considerations

> test against a dev database on the server

Firebase doesn't offer a dev server, but it does provide emulators. You can run a local instance of firestore and redirect your tests to it. Have a look at the testing suite:

[Setting up a firestore emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup) | 
[Testing SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk#readme)